# Call Javascript on IdleMonitor Timeout and then call a AJAX method in Primefaces

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a idle monitor on my web app like this:

```
<p:idleMonitor timeout="10000" onidle="timeout()"  />
```

The timeout is a javascript and using the javascript I want to invoke a `<p:ajax>` like this:

```
<script>
function timeout(){
    timer();
}
</script>
```

And the `<p:ajax>` is something like this:

```
<p:ajax id="timer" listener="#{package.timeout()}"/>
```

Is this possible? Or what are the alternative solutions that **don't use a Primfaces DialogBox or a Remote Command**?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `p:remoteCommand`?

Comment: Check the documentation and showcase http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/idleMonitor.xhtml

Answer (score 0):

You can use `p:ajax` directly in `p:idleMonitor` like so:

```
<p:idleMonitor timeout="10000">
  <p:ajax event="idle" listener="#{bean.method}" />
</p:idleMonitor>
```